# How do you extend collection(?) to include second, third, etc. functions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, object, extend

Pretty self explanatory.

I use array_name.first to get the first element. How do you extend it to get second, third, random, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it is already there, in Ruby 1.9.2 at least.

If it weren't there, I would create a file in config/initializers called array_helper.rb (or whatever) and add the following code:

```
class Array
  def second
    self[1]
  end
end
```

Why? Because all classes in Ruby are open and you can extend anything you want.

Here's some tricks to know:

When working in the console, if you want to test the file, be sure to use `rails console` and not `irb`. Also, do `reload!` after creating or updating the above file. Finally, all objects must be recreated to use the new code after `reload!`.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby you can just reopen any existing class and add your own functions.

In rails, you already have those methods defined in activesupport

See the source at github: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb